# Images do not load on https, site breaks down on certain links

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal, https

The website I am having issues with is www.trommelo.org, it uses DRUPAL as a CMS. I am having problems when I access the site in CHROME @ https://trommelo.org.

When on http (on certain links) I get this error:

Error 107 (net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR): SSL protocol error.

The Input field on the browser changes the path to my server on an https connection.

I spoke with support at Rackspace and they concluded it was the .htaccess file. They said that there was only support on http and not https for js and css with gzip.

Is there a https line of code I could/should put in here? Help greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  # Serve gzip compressed CSS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css $1\.css\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve gzip compressed JS files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js $1\.js\.gz [QSA]

  # Serve correct content types, and prevent mod_deflate double gzip.
  RewriteRule \.css\.gz$ - [T=text/css,E=no-gzip:1]
  RewriteRule \.js\.gz$ - [T=text/javascript,E=no-gzip:1]

 <FilesMatch "(\.js\.gz|\.css\.gz)$">
   # Serve correct encoding type.
   Header set Content-Encoding gzip
   # Force proxies to cache gzipped & non-gzipped css/js files separately.
   Header append Vary Accept-Encoding
 </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: This error is reported during SSL negotiation - therefore is unlikely to have anything to do with HTTP / content negotiation. You will not get this error "When on http" - only with HTTPS.

Comment: Everything seems to run fine on http but, certain links on the site bounce me to https with the path of my server and the file I was clicking on.